# Hibernate Inheritance Single_table

Tags: hibernate, inheritance

I have setup my classes like below. Hibernate ddl generates 2 tables Admin and Customer. I would have expected only one table as per the SINGLE_TABLE strategy.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseUser{
...
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Admin extends BaseUser{
...
}


@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Customer extends BaseUser{
@OneToMany
private List<Order> orders;
...
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems to work all though unsure why @MappedSuperclass doesnt.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
public abstract class BaseUser{
...
}

@Entity
public class Admin extends BaseUser{
...
}


@Entity
public class Customer extends BaseUser{
@OneToMany
private List<Order> orders;
...
}
```

Comment: I told you...it's essentially the same as what I posted (leaving out default configurations). Read up on the link I posted about @MappedSuperclass. It does the exact opposite of what you're after - having a separate table for each sub class (each with columns for the super class fields).

Comment: No it's not. I tried your suggestion. I cannot get it to work using @MappedSuperclass even if I define it on the superclass.

Comment: That must be a misunderstanding. The code in your question uses `@MappedSuperclass` which is wrong. My answer uses `@Inheritance` (and not `@MappedSuperclass`) to produce what you need. The reference in my answer to `@MappedSuperclass` is there to explain how to use it and why it's inappropriate for your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

No, single-table inheritance works differently. The inheritance strategy needs to be defined on the super class. See the [JPA Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Example_single_table_inheritance_table) for reference.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="USER_TYPE")
@Table(name="USER")
public abstract class BaseUser{
...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("A")
public class Admin extends BaseUser{
...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("C")
public class Customer extends BaseUser{
@OneToMany
private List<Order> orders;
...
}
```

Note that depending on your database you may or may not be allowed to call your table `USER`. There's also an [example for how to use @MappedSuperclass](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Example_mapped_superclass_tables).

Comment: I dont think this is true...the subclasses should inherit the inheritance strategy. In any case this doesn't work either.